# Memory leak in iOS with Profiler

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

Looking at the memory profiler, It shows an increase in memory usage, slow but steady. It all in the following 2 lines in `NSStream` `Delegate`:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
    {
        if (theStream == inputStream) {
            int bytesRead = 0;
            static uint8_t buffer[1024];
            bytesRead = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)]; -- this line causing the memory to grow
            //[inBuffer appendBytes:buffer length:bytesRead];
            //Do something
        }
        break;
    }

  }
```

I would think the buffer gets filled every time it gets there and flushed since its local. So what's the problem?

Comment: maybe you need show more code related to the leak

Comment: I do not believe the problem rests in the code you've shared with us. If you're looking a leaks in profiler, it shows you where the leaked object was allocated, but it will not (cannot) show you the source of the leak. BTW, did you run this code through the static analyzer ("Analyze" on Xcode's "Product" menu)?

Comment: No, I did not run it through the static Analyzer, I will give it a try. It may be possible that some other code is the problem, but there is hardly any code anywhere else that I can think of, this test is as simple as reading the bytes into the buffer like I showed. When I do comment that one line, memory becomes steady.

Comment: FYI, you say "I would think the buffer gets filled every time it gets there and flushed since its local." The very definition of `static` is that it won't get flushed. But it's the same address every time, so I also don't see how the mere existence of the buffer (nor reading anything into that) would cause memory growth. I really think the problem certainly rests elsewhere. If you get a clean bill of health from the analyzer, then update your question, including a little more code, but it makes no sense that a `static` could be a source of a leak.

Comment: I will do. Yes, static isn't the problem, I have tested with and without.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine.

If you are looking in Allocation Summary, "Overall Bytes" will be ever-increasing as it includes Transient Bytes as well (which are temporary). Make sure you are observing "Live Bytes" / "# Living".
Also, the code looks so efficient, it is not allocating memory of its own on each cycle. The 'static' variable is just coping content on its already allocated space. So even if some allocation is being shown, that might be because of the 'read' method.

PS: you may also want to check if the NSStream object is actually of a custom derived type and if it has some custom implementation of 'read' method.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, I tried all the profiler tools, it wasn't helping and the memory was still growing steady, I stripped it down to the very simple code shown above and memory was still growing. Out of frustration, I ended up copying my code into a new blank project, ran it and the memory looks steady. I have no clue what was the cause of this weird behavior. Note this app handles IP/TCP data at high speeds.